# How to join table to itself and select max values in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a `contracts` table:

```
contractId    date       price     partId
1             20120121   10        1
2             20110130   9         1
3             20130101   15        2
4             20110101   20        2
```

The contract with greatest `date` being the active contract (don't blame me, I blame infor for creating xpps)

I need to create query to see only active contracts  (one contract per part, the contract with highest date).

So the result of the query should be like this:

```
contractId    date       price     partId
1             20120121   10        1
3             20130101   15        2
```

I am out of ideas here, I tried self joining the table, I tried aggregation functions, but I can't figure it out. If anyone would have any idea, please share them with me..

Comment: What rdbms like MySql or Sql-Server are you using?

Comment: `query` is just fine with just a single `r` ...

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake, i am a little bit tired sitting whole day in front of telnet emulator trying to figure out this querry.. I am using the DB/2 on IBM AS/400.

Comment: Based on the tags, the dbms is officially "DB2 for i".  (The system is currently known as IBM PowerSystem running IBM i. They haven't sold an AS/400 since 2000.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this will work on almost all RDBMs,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName A
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT partID, MAX(date) maxDate
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY partID
        ) B on a.partID = b.partID AND
                a.date = b.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ea54/1)

if your RDBMS supports `Window Function`,

```
SELECT  contractId ,date, price,partId
FROM    
(
    SELECT contractId ,date, price,partId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartID
                                ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
) s
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4df6/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contracts c
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT partId, MAX([date]) AS MaxDate
        FROM contracts
        GROUP BY partID
    ) MaxDate
        ON c.partId = MaxDate.partID
            AND c.[date] = MaxDate.[date]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the fast self join:

```
SELECT c1.*  FROM contracts c1   
LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts c2 ON c2.partId = c1.partId AND c1.date < c2.date 
WHERE c2.contractId IS NULL
```

The use of sub selects (nested selects) tend to be slower.