# when querying a list of items(in) can I apply filters to each item?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm querying financal database for a group of companies but I only want the most recent year for each.

```
select ticker, date 
from company."financials_Income_Statement_yearly" fisy 
where ticker in ('IBM.US', 'AAPL.US')
order by date desc
```

I get something like this:

```
IBM.US  2020-12-31
AAPL.US 2020-09-30
IBM.US  2019-12-31
AAPL.US 2019-09-30
IBM.US  2018-12-31
AAPL.US 2018-09-30
IBM.US  2017-12-31
AAPL.US 2017-09-30
IBM.US  2016-12-31
```

In this case I only want the most recent result, which is the first 2 rows.

When I'm sending hundreds of items in a list, is there a easy way to do this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for a filter exactly - this is a case where a self-join can be used:

```
SELECT a.* FROM company."financials_Income_Statement_yearly" a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ticker, MAX(date) maxDate
  FROM company."financials_Income_Statement_yearly"
  WHERE ticker in ('IBM.US', 'AAPL.US')
  GROUP BY ticker
) b
ON a.ticker = b.ticker
AND a.date = b.maxDate
```

(not tested)

[How to join table to itself and select max values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630855/139010)

Answer (score 1):

First Step is to create the rank per row based on Ticker in the most recent order (date desc). Then filter that rank_ with 1

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d435469c1e288e5004e5d04e08e2fba

```
with ranking_data as (
select 
ticker,
date,
row_number() over(partition by ticker order by date desc) as rank_
from "financials_Income_Statement_yearly"
where ticker in ('IBM.US', 'AAPL.US')

)

select ticker, date from ranking_data where rank_ = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Postgres uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ticker) fisy.*
from company."financials_Income_Statement_yearly" fisy 
where ticker in ('IBM.US', 'AAPL.US')
order by ticker, date desc
```